# MySql query error near WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My code is

```
$user_query = '
     UPDATE  
          users  
     SET  
          `password`="$password",  
          `email`="$email", 
          `position`="$position", 
     WHERE  
          `username`=".$uname."';
$user_result = mysql_query($user_query, $connection);
confirm_query($user_result);
```

When I run this query it gives me an error:

> Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `username`=".$uname."' at line 7

Can any body help me resolve this error?

Comment: there's an extra comma after the position name/value pair. Also, you're missing concatenation marks for the password, email and position variables.

Comment: The quotes are all off too. You use single quotes and expect the var to be used, then double quotes and concatenation. Echo the string to see what you end up with.

Comment: thank you all, for your comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is in single quotes, so the variables aren't parsed.  As you can see in error, the string is literally

```
`username`=".$uname."
```

You need to either use double quotes around the enitre thing, to parse variables correctly.

```
$user_query = "
 UPDATE  
      users  
 SET  
      `password`='$password',  
      `email`='$email', 
      `position`='$position'
 WHERE  
      `username`='$uname'";
```

Or correctly use the string concatanation operator, `.`.

```
$user_query = '
 UPDATE  
      users  
 SET  
      `password`="'.$password.'",  
      `email`="'.$email.'", 
      `position`="'.$position.'"
 WHERE  
      `username`="'.$uname.'"';
```

As others have noted, there's also an extra `,` after `postion="$position"`.

Comment: thank you the error was gone, i was stuck on this for hours, you save my life lol.. thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma `,` before the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

There is a trailing comma between `position="$position",` and the `where` clause. Remove the comma just before the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Just change quotes, and better escape data with DB driver funcs like `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Difference between quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/765634

Escaping: http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Complete query:

```
$user_query = <<<SQL
     UPDATE  
          users  
     SET  
          `password`="{$password}",  
          `email`="{$email}", 
          `position`="{$position}", 
     WHERE  
          `username`="{$uname}"
SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE  
          users  
     SET  
          `password`="$password",  
          `email`="$email", 
          `position`="$position"
     WHERE  
          `username`=".$uname."';
```

You had a trailing `,` after position

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma after `position`="$position". Remove that.